# Find a key in a matrix of numbers

Tags: cipher

I have following matrix and I need to find a key from that. The key should probably consist of 1-8 lowercase letters or digits. I have basically no hints how to find the solution or what exactly the key is (it can be word or just random set of chars).

I tried:

- Use every single number as the key
- Produce image based on the number (higher number -> darker pixel)
- Produce image based on odd/even number
  None of above was successful by any mean.

[image: matrix to solve]

Only thing that was partially successful was mark similar numbers. As you can see on image below all the similar numbers are in the same distance from each other. But I don't know what to do with that information.

[image: Similar numbers]

Here are the numbers copied from excel in raw form.

```
542 508 630 4907    4844    4912    4961    5076    1578    4962    1594    2085    313 31  9011    8   3185    3317    7476    6019    3318    3099    3086    8382    8596    6412
78  8268    8211    443 8129    3914    8249    8278    2278    8135    2181    127 1833    753 133 43  2456    3913    2334    8070    8198    2238    3836    1704    104 5438
7006    300 557 191 138 7653    279 309 304 145 261 607 195 9   525 383 236 114 239 2861    1559    642 7701    1805    5486    1853
7217    9943    42  173 4922    4215    6203    223 4019    2880    3867    13  1612    82  812 1453    4945    6599    2353    1299    192 4357    5955    7670    742 2802
6839    9840    798 991 7834    101 493 434 8685    373 6234    1214    149 5953    271 102 5389    3037    100 316 75  467 4495    4755    9369    4804
1243    9494    224 619 8412    2381    189 2139    201 5507    5068    1051    1407    6115    273 787 8435    8719    1894    1825    810 2309    3320    6507    3141    288
564 9890    4392    2267    6670    811 415 3028    21  3329    8553    4463    12  9237    8357    5051    7724    1738    5689    2797    683 9002    5367    7088    4714    7135
2082    9644    34  7159    7258    153 2957    1163    8581    666 890 9829    8092    8175    909 379 7277    7873    1278    801 8742    6911    3304    5064    1924    8416
2976    9501    8424    113 766 3617    2525    6830    2515    2011    2721    169 1877    3121    601 8013    788 1013    319 54  2070    421 5355    8549    2818    6675
879 9742    6395    829 1972    7411    3705    5368    3694    4663    3895    5282    420 513 3695    5740    3050    5351    3309    6   4661    5827    8262    767 712 7262
6775    9763    4054    4125    4094    229 5055    492 1225    281 5041    4994    1646    1730    5061    5018    5017    5529    3853    8867    3797    758 7977    2716    6622    771
5317    2624    2634    2691    2640    108 1109    67  359 2443    1495    6580    8670    8759    1515    1469    1468    8847    1376    1328    1457    1564    605 3891    5163    1977
5032    9315    9414    9390    9478    9327    5074    5019    4940    4929    1786    5055    5084    5079    4938    4429    5530    2123    7390    4290    5511    7314    1820    4923    4873    5005
1484    2303    2406    2382    2469    2315    1529    1470    1391    1383    8812    1509    1538    1534    1389    757 3636    1540    3516    5747    5878    3423    8847    137 1328    1457
4442    6142    6153    6206    6159    307 9796    929 5537    5506    2090    7208    4496    7198    499 7395    8605    1945    2032    7199    4429    5530    1031    7390    4290    5511
5905    823 4985    2213    4992    2437    5947    953 5812    5803    1541    5928    5956    3460    5810    3365    5868    1490    1520    3383    5891    3636    1540    3516    5747    5878
3267    163 6060    1637    6030    647 9536    727 6119    6763    2087    3289    3321    3316    1949    3276    7445    4951    828 3294    571 6111    347 3160    3112    6095
8515    4547    2544    9157    2514    388 9721    8503    2601    8237    3565    2591    8568    83  2567    881 351 7027    977 8546    23  2595    2141    8413    8364    2577
7940    1609    3723    587 3693    1616    7549    7926    3781    523 5615    1493    7990    3511    3746    7307    1577    9311    1279    57  6451    3774    2503    289 7785    3756
1781    59  8965    2713    8936    1776    3391    2440    9024    5209    1652    509 1837    743 409 1823    1745    1319    1715    2671    257 6558    859 5643    1625    8997
7648    4826    8377    899 4280    7644    9904    8284    4366    3911    2980    8053    7702    4129    4330    4243    7613    3209    2925    199 661 1857    1399    913 7490    4342
4734    4564    4648    9273    4794    4728    4775    4719    4642    1201    6301    4756    4784    1723    4640    7669    4697    907 4669    9213    4813    9465    8081    9348    4576    4707
6486    663 418 3285    387 6482    9628    7124    482 452 314 3114    6536    3104    445 3303    6450    256 291 3105    6904    4223    312 3297    6332    456
7066    6897    6984    4616    7125    7062    7108    7054    6978    6968    6937    7089    7117    4633    6975    4538    7031    7032    7003    4556    7053    4808    7036    4693    6910    7041
```

The cipher is from magazine [vesmir](https://vesmir.cz), but the way to get to this exact table is a secret.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Why is it a secret? Is there some reason you can't tell us? Knowing how the puzzle works up until this point likely will be useful for moving forward with it.

Comment: Maybe secret is not the right word, but it's basically impossible to get to this point without printed version of the magazine.  But principally the previous parts was about decoding binary numbers to text and counting nth most used word in the text.